# Rendering React search bar inline with rest of header

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

New to React and I have the following `Header.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './styles/styles.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faSearch, faBars } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="header">
      {/* Left section */}
      <div className="header-left">
        <Link to="/" className="coffee-icon">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} className="coffee" />
        </Link>
        <div className="search-bar">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="search-icon" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search" className="search-input" />
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div className="header-right">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} className="menu-icon" />
        <span className="user-name">Some User</span>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

And the following `styles.css`:

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

.header {
    background-color: #6858ca;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .coffee {
    color: #9a8edf;
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  
  .search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #52459c;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  
  .search-icon {
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .search-input {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .menu-icon {
    color: #9a8edf;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  
  .user-name {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

I am trying to get the coffee icon to appear on the left side of the header, and then after a short amount of space, add the search bar. Instead what I get is the searchbar appearing *down* 1 line, and slightly indented to the right:
[image]

**How can I fix this and get the search bar appearing to the right of the coffee icon?**

Comment: Just apply ```display:flex``` to ```header-left``` class.

Comment: Thanks @Nexo, like so: `<div className="header-left display:flex">`? If so, that doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: For css part, you need to add not in class.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your (rather brief) comments, I could sure use a full working example if you or anyone else can spare it!

Comment: You can take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All you need to do is set `.header-left` to flex.

```css
.header-left{
   display:flex;
}
```

- the reason for applying flex to `header-left` is because coffe icon item

```
<Link to="/" className="coffee-icon"></Link>
```

and

```
<div className="search-bar"></div>
```

search bar are direct child for `header-left`.

- To put them next to each other we need to make their parent compoent as flex.

---

As a example code:

```css
.header-left {
  display: flex;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}


/* not needed just for visuals */

.icon {
  background: #c5c5c5;
}
```

```html
<p>With applying flex</p>
<div class="header-left">
  <div class="icon">Coffee Icon</div>
  <div><input type="text" placeholder="search..."></div>
</div>
<p>Without applying flex</p>
<div>
  <div class="icon">Coffee Icon</div>
  <div><input type="text" placeholder="search..."></div>
</div>
```